# Setting position of div using JQuery, when Transition is applied on Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have applied CSS:`transition: all 1s ease-in-out;` to a `absolute` positioned `DIV` now I am resetting the position of `div` on click of a button, div is setting properly, but there is a small div inside absolute positioned div, which is not setting properly. following is my code([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/73s2c/)):

> The pointer will set at desired location if transition is removed from
>   CSS

HTML:

```
<div class="target">Here</div>
<div class="mobile">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="traingle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.target').on('click',function(){
    var position= $(this).offset(),
    widt = $(this).outerWidth(),
    heigh = $(this).outerHeight();

    $('.mobile')
    .offset({
        left:position.left+widt-350,
        top:(position.top+heigh+20)
    });
    $('.traingle')
    .offset({
        left:position.left-7+(widt/2)
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.target{
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.mobile{width:350px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:9px;
    background-color:#1abc9c;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper{position:relative;}
.traingle{width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 17.3px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #01abc9 transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:-16px;
    left;0px;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73s2c/),

> the pointer will set properly if you remove transition effect.

Answer (score 0):

I modified it a bit.

```
$('.target').on('click',function(){
var position= $(this).offset(),
widt = $(this).outerWidth(),
heigh = $(this).outerHeight();
$('.mobile').css('top',(position.top+heigh+20))
.animate({
    left:position.left+widt-350,        
},1000,function(){
    $('.traingle')
.offset({
    left:position.left-7+(widt/2)
});

});
```

});

Instead of CSS transitions, can you use jquery animate function? By using animate you can accomplish that task. Here is a link:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/73s2c/4/

This may not be perfect but still you can work on it to improve it.

Comment: :) this will a generic function, can't do that.. everytime the position of button will be changed

Comment: @BharatSoni Unless I'm misunderstanding the need, i think you should have another look at the original answer of setting the `right` property through `css`.  You say it needs to be generic, but this approach is generic since the `right` is relative to its container.  As long as the container is put in the correct place the relative position of the triangle should be constant.  Perhaps not `0` as the code had it, but some constant.